# How to build a Full C Parser using pyparsing?

Tags: python, c, parsing, yacc, pyparsing

I am trying to build a full C Parser using pyparsing.

Actually what I want for my project is to identify certain lines of code in a C Program of interest to me. Eg. Complex Assignment instructions with typecasting, pointer dereference etc.

I thought, since I am investing the effort, I will implement the Full C Grammar in pyparsing, and use just what I need.

I referred to this C Grammar for YACC and wrote it according to pyparsing (to the best of my limited understanding of pyparsing).
http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/ANSI-C-grammar-y.html#translation-unit

What I get however is that pyparsing gets stuck in an infinite loop. I have uploaded the python code here.
https://gist.github.com/gkernel/18cd1d38376d07db989a

I need help in this. Please also tell me an alternative approach to solve my problem if you know any.

EDIT:
To be clear, there could be a bug in the code, but I have already invested effort in checking that I have written the correct grammar. I basically want to ask if pyparsing can be used for something as complicated as this.

One of the things I have done is Forward() declare all the non-terminals in the grammar, and I want to know if this is the right approach. I did this because Python would complain of some names being undefined.

Comment: You should move your code into your actual post. Links change/die.

Comment: I deemed it better to put it outside, because it is too long. I will also put it here.

Comment: If it's long, give us a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't understand how to put the code here, and what would be a minimal example of Grammar for the C language. I have provided with a python file that can be downloaded and run, to help you help me. I don't think putting a piece of that code, which would not mean anything, will help.

Can you also please point out, what is the problem with having a link to the code, especially when it is too long and easier to read elsewhere?

Comment: You are correct not to post such a large file, but then again, "There is an error somewhere in this 400+ lines of code. Please find it" isn't a very good question. Changing it to "**How* can I find the error" may be better suited to Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Jongware OK. I understand. Reframed my question. I don't need you to find me the bug, I have put effort on that. I want you to check if I am using pyparsing in the correct way, and if there are some alternative approaches.

Comment: Not to rain on your parade, but building parsers that work on real  code (for C, C++, or really for almost any modern language) is actually a lot of work: the reference manuals are huge, the lexical definitions are complex, you need to have a preprocessor, the grammar is hard to get right, it depends on vendor and version who don't document what they actually did, your parser generator has restrictions, ... and then you have the problems of "Life after Parsing" (see my bio by clicking on my name in this comment).  *People just don't seem to get this*.  ...

Comment: ... I build professional parsers for a living, partly because "being hard" makes it a unique service/product.  But the amount of effort it takes to do this is much bigger than you'd expect; I've been doing it for 20 years; more power to you if you can do it faster than that.  If you really want to get on with end task ("identifying certain lines...") you'd be far better to get a real, working parser, and get on with your technical tasks.  (Doesn't have to be mine; consider GCC, EDG, Clang, ...).

Comment: ... Your alternative is to give up on accurate parsing, and simply hack something together with Perl.  For tasks of limited duration and value, this may be effective, yes, you'll have to hand adjust the answers, but that's lot cheaper than building a real parser, or even getting one from somebody else and learning how to bend it to  your will.

Comment: [PS: the grammar you linked to seems to date from 1995.  I doubt if it matches any existing C compiler.]

Comment: @IraBaxter Thank you for your comment. I do understand now that I was being too naive! I thought a working Lex/Yacc grammar should automatically work out for what I wanted to do. I will take the easy way out of hacking something together for assignment expressions.

Comment: @IraBaxter, you said that `building parsers that work on real code is actually a lot of work`. But why is that required? Aren't most languages open source, and hence can't we use their own parser? Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Many languages are not open source; that clearly won't work for them.  Of those that *are* open source, extracting a working parser is hard work, *if* you even have the right tools to do it.  If you found a compiler implemented in OCAML, would you be able to extract the parser? (I doubt you have an OCAML compiler or know how to use one, so much for that idea).  If you did extract the parser, you'll find its in OCAML, and you want to build an application in C.  How are you going to glue them together?  Finally, just because you extracted it, doesn't mean it does what you want.  Life's a bitch.

Comment: .... if my argument isn't convincing, go try to extract the C parser from GCC.  Call me when you've finished.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, `pyparsing` creates recursive-descent grammars. Recursive-descent grammars will go into an infinite loop if presented with a left-recursive grammar, and it is most likely that the rather ancient C grammar you unearthed (and any more modern C grammar) will be left-recursive, since such grammars are easier to write and are acceptable input to LALR(1) and GLR parser generators, like `bison`.

C is not an easy language to parse, and more so if you don't understand the basics of parsing theory. If your goal is to learn parsing theory, I'd suggest that you try a simpler language. If your only goal is to parse C, as indicated in your question, then I'd suggest you use one of the available tools; both `gcc` and `clang` come with (unfortunately underdocumented) mechanisms to access the parse tree for a C program, and there are commercial products as well if you have a budget.

Comment: You are right. I had lost grip on my Compiler Construction Basics, and did some reading over the weekend. If you care, I will try to hack something using pyparsing, to parse just the assignment expressions. Infact, I have "small" set of variations in the assignment expressions, as I am parsing a generated code. Hopefully this should be much easier, and less naive than what I wanted to do earlier.